# Error appending text in ( nonexistant ) textbox due to async callback

Tags: c#, winforms

I have written some code that works quite well : the program opens an async socket with the server, and writes in a textarea whatever the server sends.

The problem is, when i close the form, I get a lot of errors, because the callback is trying to write in the textarea that, obviously, is not there anymore.

Here is the method that writes on the textarea :

```
private void appendText(string s)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action<string>(appendText), new object[] { s });
        return;
    }

    SocketStream.AppendText(s + "\r\n");
}
```

and here is the part of the callback's code calling said method :

```
string[] arr = txt.Split(new char[1]);

foreach (string t in arr)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(t) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t))
    {
        appendText( t);
    }  
}
```

is there a way to prevent those errors from happening?
I've already tried adding a

```
if(SocketStream != null)
```

but it didn't seemed to work.

Comment: Is `SocketStream` your TextArea? And what is the exact exception being thrown?

Comment: I think you want to close the socket in the FormClose event handler, or do something similar.

Comment: Yes, SocketStream is my textBox. The exception is not in english, so I'm not sure writing it would be of any help... but I guess it would sound like "Error , trying to write on non existant object"

Answer (score 1):

When you close your form you probably need to stop reading from your Async socket, as well as stop writing to your `TextBox`. You'll need to have some state, some boolean perhaps, that makes all the processes stop. Now I don't know the specifics of your situation, but you could think of something like:

```
public class YourForm
{
    private bool _formClosing = false; // Keep track of form closing

    public YourForm()
    {    
        this.FormClosing += FormClosingHandler;
    }

    protected void FormClosingHandler(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        _formClosing = true;
    }

    private void appendText(string s)
    {
      if (_formClosing) // If form is closing, we dont want to append anymore
        return;

      if (InvokeRequired)
      {
          this.Invoke(new Action<string>(appendText), new object[] { s });
          return;
      }

      SocketStream.AppendText(s + "\r\n");
    }

    // Socket handling; also check for _formClosing
}
```

You need to include the same check for your socket as well, to stop it from reading more data and gracefully disposing of the socket/connection. Again I'm making some assumptions/guesses here, but this might push you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Can you unsubscribe from the callback event before you close the `Form`?

You can do this with the `-=` operator, in the `Closing` handler of your `Form`.